# Accessing text field within iframe from parent document and store for use

Tags: javascript

I have two documents - **main.html (parent document)** and **enterKey.html (child document)**.

Within main.html

```
<script>
...
</script>
<iframe id="key" src="enterKey.html"></iframe>
```

Within enterKey.html:

```
<input id="sbox" type="text">
```

I am trying to access the value entered in sbox for use in **main.html**. But because the user will be continuously updating **sbox** I need for the updates to be reflected in **main.html**.

For example if the user types into sbox "hello worlx" then corrects it a second later to "hello world" then the change must be reflected immediately in the parent document.

How can this be achieved?

I've been looking at using `document.getElementById('key').contentWindow.sbox` but don't know how to use it in the context of my example.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to set the onchange function on the field and they you can access elements on the parent page with:

```
parent.document.getElementById("id")
```

Example:

In the enterKey.html you would set the onchange for your text field by:

```
<input id="sbox" type="text" onChange="enterKeyFunc()">
```

Then also in enterKey.html you would have a function called enterKeyFunc() or something that would look kinda like this:

```
function enterKeyFunc()
{
    parent.document.getElementById("mainHTMLFieldId").value = document.getElementById("sbox").value;
}
```

Then in main.html make sure that the field you wanted to keep synced has an id of "mainHTMLFieldID" and that should do it.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Edit again:

I think if you want to set a variable in the parent change the above js from

```
parent.document.getElementById("mainHTMLFieldId").value = document.getElementById("sbox").value;
```

to

```
parent.globalVariableName = document.getElementById("sbox").value;
```

This of course would only work if the variable you are trying to set is a global variable on the parent page.  I haven't done this for a long time personally but I believe this can be done.

Comment: I edited my above answer.  Comments don't format well.  At least I don't know who to do it right.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply - but I would like to store the value in a variable and not in a field

Comment: Blenders method would work to get the value at any given point but since you want them to stay synced I personally believe it presents some problems.  Unless you are very regularly copying the value from sbox back into that variable you would have old data.  His method goes parent->child.  My method moves in the other direction child->parent and would make sure that when ever the value of sbox in the frame was changed it would propagate back up to the parent.  The first part of your question has the same problem.  The state will not hold unless all monitoring is done at the frame level.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit more simple than you think:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('key').contentWindow;
var value = iframe.getElementById('sbox').value;
```

Just treat the `iframe` as a new `document` element.

Comment: Is there a way to return an alert as the user types into sbox? For example - if 's' is entered into sbox - s is alerted in the parent document and if 'o' is entered then 'so' is alerted (just for testing purposes).